# Is it possible to implement swagger in .NET project with Global.asax pipeline?

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, owin, global-asax, swagger-ui

I need to implement **Swagger** for my **WEB API**. Since my project is using a **Global.asax** file, I couldn't implement **Swagger**.

Is there any way to implement **Swagger** in this case?

Comment: You just need to use [Swashbuckle](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Swashbuckle). It does the job for you. Just grab the nuget package and configure it and you have your Swagger endpoint.

Comment: @llyaChernomordik  With out **OWIN** in the project, can we able to use this nuget for  **swagger** ?

Comment: I don't see any dependencies on OWIN there and don't remember it was required. You can just try and add it to you project to verify 100%.